# Getting an Operand should contain 1 column(s) error when merging values of two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I'll try to explain it the best I can. My English is not very good.

I want to combine values from two tables. It works fine when I only merge one table, like so:

```
SELECT `friendid`,`friendname`, (SELECT `islogged` FROM `account_data` WHERE `guildcard` = `friendid` ) FROM `guild_data` WHERE `accountid` = '42000007' ORDER BY `friendid` DESC LIMIT 0, 40
```

But I need two entries from the "account_data" table. I thought I could do it like this:

```
SELECT `friendid`,`friendname`, (SELECT `islogged`,`lastonline` FROM `account_data` WHERE `guildcard` = `friendid` ) FROM `guild_data` WHERE `accountid` = '42000007' ORDER BY `friendid` DESC LIMIT 0, 40
```

But apparently that isn't correct, and it throws me an error, namely:

```
[Err] 1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

How can I make this work with 2 columns? Both values should be taken from the row with the `guildcard` value found from `friendid`.

Hope I've been clear enough.

Comment: Please read the following document on how to ask a question here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks, you've made it much clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need to use a JOIN. Try this:

```
SELECT g.friendid, g.friendname, a.islogged, a.lastonline
FROM guild_data g
LEFT OUTER JOIN account_data a
ON g.friendid = a.guildcard
WHERE g.accountid = '42000007'
ORDER BY g.friendid DESC LIMIT 0, 40
```

Using a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` will ensure that you get results in `guild_data` that don't have rows in `account_data`. If you know that you will always have a corresponding row in `account_data` or if you want to exclude rows in `guild_data` that don't map to anything in `account_data`, use `INNER JOIN` instead.

If this doesn't give you the results you want, please let us know what is wrong with it. Post what you got with this query and what you expected to get.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did not understand how JOIN works, but now I do, thanks to your explanation. This method displays the desired results without errors.